# Express post not receive JSON data [close]

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, post

I have this problem because I am sending data via JavaScript using XMLHttpRequest but not receiving it in node.js express post method. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My script - funcion form execute on window load

```
function form() {
  const btn = document.getElementById("save-data");
  let currentPage = window.location.href.split("/").at(-1);

  function sendData(data) {
    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHR.open("POST", window.location.href);
    XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    console.log(data); // I get right data
    XHR.send(data);
  }

  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    switch (currentPage) {
      case "settings":
        const prefix = document.getElementById("prefix").value;
        let buttonState = document.getElementById("module-state");

        if (buttonState.hasAttribute("enable")) {
          buttonState = "enable";
        } else {
          buttonState = "disable";
        }

        sendData({
          prefix: prefix,
          buttonState: buttonState,
          announcements: {
            giveawayChannelID: 123,
            updateChannelID: 123,
          },
        });
    }
  });
}
```

My Node.js code

```
router.post('/:id/settings', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body) // {}
})
```

Pleas help.

Comment: You might find the Fetch API much easier to work with.  It's well-supported in browsers.  We haven't generally needed XHR in many years.  :-)

Comment: Have you enabled the body parser in Express?

Comment: No, I don't enable this. How to do it ?

Comment: The `send` function does not accept an object, it will be turned into a string `'[object Object]'` which should cause an error when parsing. Make sure to use `XHR.send(JSON.stringify(data));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install body-parser package by NPM, and require it in your code

Try

```
npm i body-parser
```

Then in your main node script, require it

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

after that, you should set it as a middleware for express

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //Handles JSON requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //Handles normal post requests
```

after these steps, you can access values like `req.body.value`

Comment: You can use `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()` these days.  No need for the separate package anymore.  (The Express developers did split this off some years ago, but then decided to merge it back in.)

Comment: I’m developing a node project rn. Last week I wanted to use these two with express and I got errors. I had to use its own package.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json  http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded